# If archaeology shows that people abandoned the ancient Trojan region around the 6th century BC, why do we have so few written evidences of that?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece, archaeology

My professor told us that people lived around the location of ancient Troy up to the beginning of the 6th century BC and moved away mostly because they couldn't deal with prices in Neorion Harbour.

If that is true, and considering all the culture and wealth the ancient peoples who lived there had, shouldn't more data about them have been found since Heinrich Schliemann's findings?

Answer (score 6):

The site around Troy was not continuously inhabited. [Troy VII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_VII), what we believe is the one associated with the famous Bronze Age Troy, was deserted in the mid-10th century BC, followed by the establishment of Troy VIII around 700 BC. That's plenty of time for people to forget about what happened before. The inhabitants may not be the same people either, which means oral traditions may be lost. The legend only survived in Ancient Greece, after all.